# Probably pretty stupid, but: opening the "visual designer" in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

All I can open at this very moment are the java scripts, but I cannot see the layout. What do I do to open it up again?

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: Where you can see everything that happens on the screen, basically.

Comment: [Here.](http://i.imgur.com/8J7OFIP.png) You'll see how simple of a question this really is; I just started using Eclipse, so I don't know how to navigate through it.

Comment: The word I was looking for is "layout." *Facepalm*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the screen for putting in Java code, not the screen for editing layouts (XML's). The only place where you can graphically look at things is in layouts. So go to the `res` folder, then `layouts`, double click on an XML file, then click some tab near the bottom of the screen that says something like `Graphical Layout`. That will show you what you want.

Comment: Oh my god. I am so extremely dumb sometimes. Thanks man.